# Minted breaksymbol not shown

Tags: fonts, fontspec, minted

I'm using the minted package, and as code font I'm using Inconsolata imported with fontspec. I have `breaklines` as true, but the default `breaksymbol` is not shown, only a square is shown.

How can I set breaksymbol so it uses a font that has `\hookrightarrow`?

Thats my document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Para saber el encoding del archivo
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{uarial}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Arial}

\usepackage[cache=false]{minted} %Para insertar código
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Inconsolata}
\fontsize{11}{14}

\DeclareFontShape{EU1}{Inconsolata(0)}{bx}{n}{<->ssub*Inconsolata(0)/m/n}{}

\begin{document}

\texttt{\hookrightarrow}
\hookrightarrow
$\hookrightarrow$
$\mathsf{\hookrightarrow}$

{\fontfamily{Asana-Math.otf}\selectfont $\hookrightarrow$}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete but minimal document which we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the problem.  `\hookrightarrow` will depend on the fonts you are using for maths and not those you are using for text.

Comment: I see the fontenc, inconsolata and urial packages and then unicode-math and related commands including using Arial as a math font which are totally unrelated. Can you really use Arial as a math font? I see nothing in the example that uses Minted!

Comment: Well, the problem was not related with minted. I discovered that the breakline symbol that minted user is `\hookrightarrow`, so minted wasn't necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using that and it works.

```
\setmathrm{Asana-Math.otf}
\setmathsf{Arial}
\setmathtt{Inconsolata}
```

When I need Arial formulas, I used `\mathsf`